# View animation interact with another view animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have 2 imageview (a imageview for a pen image, and a imageview for a line, both are drawable), that each one has it own view animation that works perfectly.
my problem is that when I start the animation for the pen I want it to interact and animate the drawing of the line in the other view animation (I want that it will show as the pen is drawing the line), how do I do that?

my xml for animation for the pen imageview is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="0%p" 
    android:toXDelta="100%p" 
    android:fromYDelta="-50%p"
    android:toYDelta="-50%p"
    android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```

my xml for animation for the line imageview is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="0%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fromXScale="0%"
    android:toXScale="100%"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    />
```

please help!

Comment: what is exactly the problem? You will probably need to include your layout

Comment: how do I do that? can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be done with the help of [animationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html). Add an animationListener for the pen's animation. In onAnimationStart method do `lineImage.startAnimation(lineAnimation);`

Sample:

```
penAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    lineImage.startAnimation(lineAnimation);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}
});
```